# rails 4 -- flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm still working on my rails 4 demo site, and I'm seeing an odd thing. In the controller it has a line like this:

```
format.html { redirect_to @widget, notice: 'Widget was successfully created.' }
```

This renders a flash message in the redirected page, which is expected. However, the css class attached to the message div is `alert alert-notice` rather than a valid Bootstrap alert class, like `alert-info`.

Where is the class being set for this flash, and how do I customize it?

Also, if I'm deleting a record via ajax, is there a way to access the core flash container to display the message via js, or do I have to show / hide my own flash message div just for ajax requests?

EDIT: my Michael Hartl inspired `layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Thanks!

EDIT 2:

Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I understand exactly how the class is being set in the flash object in this case. I am interested in learning how to use and customize the `notice:` in the `format.html` block. It seems there should be a way to pass a class via this notice? Or is this not a core Rails way of doing things?

Comment: That depends on your views. Look at your `views/layouts/application.html.*` file and see where it's rendering the `flash` content.

Comment: But alert alert-notice IS valid bootstrap class. You can always flash [:yourchoiceofalert] before the redirect action

Comment: You might need to remove scaffold.css from your assets, as it scrambles some bootstrap classes

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis-- http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts -- I don't see alert-notice as a valid class. Am I missing something? Also, there's no scaffold.css in my assets. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, notice is not a case, what I meant to point out is that you need to have the word alert like "alert alert-'class'". Sorry for misleading, should I have done so.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In `application.html.erb`, you would be displaying the `flash` messages.

Update that code as below

```
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info" %>
  <% end %>
```

You can add the classes that you want to apply to the flash message in the `class` option.

**EDIT**

The class is setup as `alert alert-notice` because of `alert alert-<%= key %>` in your code.
When you call `redirect_to @widget, notice: 'Widget was successfully created.`

A flash message would be added in `flash` hash with key as `notice` and value as `Widget was successfully created.`, i.e.,

```
flash[:notice] = "Widget was successfully created."
```

**EDIT #2**

`format.html { redirect_to @widget, notice: 'Widget was successfully created.' }`

`notice: 'Widget was successfully created.'` is an argument passed to `redirect_to` method. It is added to `flash` hash in this method.

Comment: thanks, I realize that that's why the class is being applied. I guess I'm asking how that `notice:` works in the `format` block, and how it's accessed and turned into a `flash` rather than passing a `flash` object.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant the `format.html` block-- how does that `notice:` element get interpreted, and where? How do you set a custom class for the flash?

Comment: @user101289 See the EDIT #2 section for the `notice: element get interpreted,` question.

Comment: If you have more questions, you should post them as a new question. Leave the comments for discussion on current question, i.e.,  `Where is the class being set for this flash, and how do I customize it?`

Answer (score 31):

Add this to

## app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController
  add_flash_types :success, :warning, :danger, :info
end
```

and then you can do this in your controllers

```
format.html { redirect_to @widget, success: 'Widget was successfully created.' }
```

provided you did this in your layouts

```
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Comment: Here are the docs for `add_flash_types`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess up with your `ApplicationController` as @Sachin Mour indicated, you can just add few addtional CSS clases, accordingly:

in `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss`:

```
/*flash*/
.alert-error {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #eed3d7;
    color: #b94a48;
    text-align: left;
 }

.alert-alert {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #eed3d7;
    color: #b94a48;
    text-align: left;
 }

.alert-success {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    color: #468847;
    text-align: left;
 }

.alert-notice {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    color: #468847;
    text-align: left;
 }
```

Step by step tutorial, how to approach flash messages with devise and bootstrap, you can find [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap)